# What is Brendan Eich’s performance optimization of the properties pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, properties

At the end of [Steve Yegge’s essay on the prototype pattern](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/10/universal-design-pattern.html), he says,

> Brendan Eich came up with astoundingly clever performance optimization for the Properties Pattern, which he told me about back in January. I was ready to publish this article, but I told him I'd hold off until he blogged about his optimization. Every once in a while he'd ping me and tell me "any day now."
>
> Brendan, it's *October*, dammit!

That note was written almost five years ago, but I can’t seem to find any information on what Eich’s optimization was. Did he or anyone else ever publish the improvement Yegge mentioned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went digging, starting from [Brendan's tweet](https://twitter.com/BrendanEich/status/367033089622409216) referred to in the other answer, and ended up [at this blog post from '08](http://www.masonchang.com/blog/2008/5/28/spidermonkeys-secret-object-sauce.html). To summarize:

> A lot of the benchmarks show that SpiderMonkey is significantly faster
>   than Tamarin. This has been mostly attributed to the way SpiderMonkey
>   accesses object properties. SpiderMonkey has an implementation of the
>   shape idea. A shape is a unique identifier which details the structure
>   of an object, and allows for a quick lookup of a given property. With
>   a few bit operations, given an object's shape and the current program
>   location, we can find a property's address.

Check the blog post for more details and references to the actual code from that time.

Comment: Thanks for doing this research!

Answer (score 3):

[Via Twitter](https://twitter.com/BrendanEich/status/367033089622409216), Brendan said,

> it's in SpiderMonkey, kinda known. Property trees => shapes, similar to hidden classes but with more sharing.

So make of that what you will.